# How can I import external files into SDL Tridion 2011 using core service?

Tags: tridion

I want to push PDF, Word and Excel files into SDL Tridion 2011 by using core service.

I tried below code but get this error:

> Invalid value for property 'BinaryContent'. Unable to open uploaded file:

```
using (ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService> factory =
    new ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService>("wsHttp_2011"))
{
  ISessionAwareCoreService client = factory.CreateChannel();
  ComponentData multimediaComponent = (ComponentData)client.GetDefaultData(
                                       ItemType.Component, "tcm:19-483-2");
  multimediaComponent.Title = "MultimediaFile";

  multimediaComponent.ComponentType = ComponentType.Multimedia;
  multimediaComponent.Schema.IdRef = "tcm:19-2327-8";

  using (StreamUploadClient streamClient = new StreamUploadClient())
  {
    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(@"\My Documents\My Poc\images.jpg",
                                              FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    string tempLocation = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent("images.jpg",
                                                           objfilestream);
  }
  BinaryContentData binaryContent = new BinaryContentData();
  binaryContent.UploadFromFile = @"C:\Documents and Settings\My Poc\images.jpg";
  binaryContent.Filename = "images.jpg";
  binaryContent.MultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData()
  {
    IdRef ="tcm:0-2-65544"
  };
  multimediaComponent.BinaryContent = binaryContent;

  IdentifiableObjectData savedComponent = client.Save(multimediaComponent,
                                                      new ReadOptions());

  client.CheckIn(savedComponent.Id, null);
  Response.Write(savedComponent.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a read of Ryan's excellent article here http://blog.building-blocks.com/uploading-images-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011

All binary files are handled the same way - so his technique for images will be equally as valid for documents, just make sure you use a Schema with the appropriate mime types.

Comment: @ Chris. I tried that code but got an error. binaryContent.MultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData() { IdRef = id }; i m trying for a jpg file can you let me know how to get this id?
There is no app.config in my project
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question explaining what you have done, show your code, and share the error you are receiving.

On another note - Would you consider committing to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 we are trying to get a dedicated SDL Tridion area on Stack Exchange. Please use your SO account so your great questions here count toward the proposal

Comment: getting below error:
Invalid value for property 'BinaryContent'. Unable to open uploaded file

Comment: Can you please update your question with your sample code? It is very hard to help you without it. It seems like your binary is not accessible or something.

Comment: @Puf has explained this clearly now - you were missing the vital step from the sample that was shared at the start. Is your code working now? Please consider committing to the proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 we need the help from every Tridion developer to get this live.

Answer (score 4):

The process for uploading binaries into Tridion using the Core Service is:

1. Upload the binary data to the Tridion server using a `StreamUploadClient`. This returns you the path of the file on the Tridion server.
2. Create a `BinaryContentData` that points to the file on the Tridion server (so with the path you got back from step 1)
3. Create a `ComponentData` that refers to the the `BinaryContentData` from step 2
4. Save the `ComponentData`

You are setting the local path for your file in step 2.

```
binaryContent.UploadFromFile = @"C:\Documents and Settings\My Poc\images.jpg";
```

But Tridion will never be able to find that file there. You instead should set the path that you got back from `UploadBinaryContent`:

```
string tempLocation;
using (StreamUploadClient streamClient = new StreamUploadClient())
{
  FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(@"\My Documents\My Poc\images.jpg",
                                            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  tempLocation = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent("images.jpg", objfilestream);
}
BinaryContentData binaryContent = new BinaryContentData();
binaryContent.UploadFromFile = tempLocation;
```

Note that the [Ryan's original code](http://blog.building-blocks.com/uploading-images-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011) does exactly that.

Comment: @ puf . Thanks a lot. It helped me a lot and i am able to upload now any file

Comment: @Frank: is that app.config  mandatory to create the multimedia components using core service from my local machine? i mean (all the images are in my local machine). and I am able to create multimedia components using core service, when the images are in the server. But i am expecting the same from my local.

Comment: Every Core Service clients needs to be instructed how to connect to Tridion Content Manager, either through a .config file (see http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithConfigFile) or through similar settings in code (see http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithoutConfigFile).