# Uploading files to SDL Tridion 2011 using Core Service stream upload (from Java)

Tags: java, tridion

To start out with, my question is based on a number of answers I have found around online, and I am hoping that someone can make a clarifying answer.

The question very short to sum it up from my current findings:
Using CoreService, it seems to be that WCF is the limitation for uploading files greater than 16,384 bytes by default. I am hoping I am just overlooking something very basic, that will allow me to upload more than just empty gif files, without having to change the server configuration, as I intend for this code to be used against multiple SDL tridion instances.

---

Just to provide context and what I have found, you may not need to read all this, but since I spent quite a bit of time looking and trying various things, I figured I might as well write it down for the next person that comes across this.

I am uploading a file, using the CoreService Stream Upload, based on this example:
[How can I import external files into SDL Tridion 2011 using core service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447494/how-can-i-import-external-files-into-sdl-tridion-2011-using-core-service)

I don't want to copy all that code, but I can successfully upload a small (empty.gif) to a temp location, using that as my basis, and I get a Windows temp file path back.

```
String tempFileLocationOnServer = streamUploadPort.uploadBinaryByteArray(
                                                                 fileName, data);
```

For slightly large file, a PDF of 80K, I get an exception:

> Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'UploadBinaryByteArray'. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 2461.

I found this [WCF readerQuotas settings - drawbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835114/wcf-readerquotas-settings-drawbacks), that seems to explain it to be an issue with WCF, and is to protect against DDOS, and that one can adjust these values.

I am thinking 80K bytes is not a lot, I am not doing anything I cannot do via the web interface with the same credentials.

And since the CoreService already requires username/password, I don't see why there would be DDOS issues, as the request should be rejected on the authentication, before the payload.

I am aware alternatives such as webdav or mapping a network drive on the Tridion instance, or using an separate webserver to dump files, so I can reference them as "external" when creating the multimedia component, but I rather not have to go that route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the title of your question (from java) there you have to notice that java parsers don't implement MTOM 100%, that is what Core Services uses for stream upload/download.

Make sure your parser supports MTOM or create a new binding and endpoint using something like this, check the messageEnconding="Text" attribute.

```
<binding name="streamUpload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200"
         transferMode="StreamedRequest" messageEncoding="Text" 
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
  <security mode="None" />
</binding>
```

It will pass all the information in base 64 (not optimal for performance but interoperable)

Comment: Thank you, I guess this was basically what I am looking for, as if I understand it correct the MTOM will allow me to upload in smaller chunks that won't make the WCF complain about too much data at once. I will have to read up on MTOM, I can see there it's not straight forward. Hopefully with a bit of reading and effort I can make it work. I will put in a working example, once I get a working solution.

Comment: Just to follow up, I tried adding the MTOM feature when creating the port to the service and adding additional bindings to try and increase the MaxArrayLength, but without any success at all. I ended up caving in to simply go to the server and change the .config file. Then it worked just fine without any client specific changes, although it does buffer rather than stream the file, but I can live with that, if files do get to big to buffer I can always resort to copy the files across on a network share.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change the size of your WCF Reader Quotas.

If you're creating your CoreService bindings programmatically (like shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithoutConfigFile)) you can just change it in your code.

If you're using an App.Config file to configure your endpoints (like the one that Tridion ships with under %Tridion%/bin/client/Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll.config) then edit this file and change its quotas.

I tend to use pretty large quotas myself, and haven't had any issues so far - as you say, access to the Core Service is usually pretty well protected.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like the ideal, being able to set it on the client side. Right now I am trying to do the same in Java, as I am using the client stub generated by executing "wsimport -s tridionsrc -extension -d tridion http://sdltridion.electridion.com/webservices/CoreService.svc?wsdl"

Comment: Note that the maximum upload size is determined as the minimum that either the server or the client allows. So whichever of the two is smaller, is what you can upload. You can easily check the defaults in the config files on your server(s) and will have to find a way to set them on your Java client.

Comment: Yes, I don't think i will have any trouble figuring out the server part, everything that is .NET is documented pretty well.